# Выдаёт ошибку при попытке запуска node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Код (Client.js):

```
Client.js
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
    config = require('./config.json');
config.cfg.intents = new Discord.Intents(config.cfg.intents);
    
const bot = new Discord.Client(config.cfg);
bot.login(config.token);
```

Вот что выдаёт в консоли:

```
ReferenceError: Client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Сергей С\Desktop\MoonBot\Client.js:1:1)
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Client.js удалите из первой строки файла Client.js

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'),
config = require('./config.json');

config.cfg.intents = new Discord.Intents(config.cfg.intents);

const bot = new Discord.Client(config.cfg);
bot.login(config.token);
```

Вам нужно убрать 1 строку

> Client.js